# How to change the values ​in the X axis to a specific difference?

Tags: pgfplots

Can someone explain how to make this graph?

[image]

I was trying to make it with `pgfplots`. I do not know how to make it appear with a difference of 25 with the percent sign.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry for my english :P

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) With `xtick difference=25`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with pure tikz:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick] (0,0) -- + (8,0);
\foreach \i/\j [count=\x from 0] in {0/ , 25/$Q_1$, 50/$Q_2$,   75/$Q3$, 100/ }
\draw[very thick] (2*\x,0.1) node[above,xshift=1ex] {\i\%} -- + (0,-0.2) node[below] {\j};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```